# HDMI splitter works only one way

Tags: hdmi, splitter

I bought a HDMI-splitter to connect multiple screens with a laptop.

Once tried, it turns out the splitter is instead meant to connect multiple devices to one single screen and having it switchable.

This exceeds my imagination, how can such technology work only one way? Is there any way to revert the splitter?

Instead of `3-input -> 1 output` I need `1-input -> 3 output`

It's a `GANA HS1080 HDMI splitter 3:1`

Comment: I think your device is misnamed: it's a selector, rather than a splitter. Notwithstanding gronostaj's answer, you can buy active devices that do what you want, such as [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Portta-Splitter-Output-Support-Blu-ray/dp/B008HZWO1S). Note that as an active device it needs its own power supply and that its HDMI standard is only 1.3, though I would expect that higher performance splitters can be found.

Comment: @AFH FYI there is such thing as a [passive HDMI splitter](https://www.amazon.ca/HDMI-Female-Splitter-Adapter-Cable/dp/B00C55DNSY) too but they don't work well.

Comment: @Romen - I had seen similar cables, but I assumed that there were some minimal electronics powered by the 5V / 50mA line.

Comment: @AFH I used to work for a store that sold them; They got returned frequently because they are truly passive and only work for short cables or hardware that can handle the violation of the HDMI spec.

Comment: @Romen - Thanks for the information: worth knowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This exceeds my imagination, how can such technology work only one way?

A simple electrical split (as with electricity, audio etc.) wouldn't work with HDMI. It uses a complex, two directional protocol, where the display device communicates its supported modes to video source and both devices are able to detect whether the other end is plugged in into a powered on device. So you can't simply reverse the splitter, the connection is asymmetrical and both directions require special handling.

> Is there any way to revert the splitter?

No.

Comment: In times of scart and vga everything seemed so easy and DIY was handy. I don't like your answer but thank you anyways :-)